# connection failure status: 0 status text:

Tags: tomcat, error-handling

I have a small web application running on a tomcat server. We've started to have users reporting an error saying:

'Connection Failure Status: 0 Status Text: '

A little bit of research suggests this is a tomcat issue?

Has anyone experienced this before and is there a resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: Would that be consistent with it working for 18 months and then this happening? What has changed is the number of users. I've changed the maxIdleTime and increased it up pretty substantially as well...

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that your web application is small, it's possible that you've left the `maxActive` attribute by default, **100**. `maxActive` stands for *the maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.* [Source.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

Comment: Hi... Thanks loads for that! Is maxActive the same as  maxThreads? (Which I have now set to 400) - I cannot see a reference to maxActive in the server.xml file?

Comment: maxThreads - "Max number of request processing threads to be created by the Http Connector, which therefore determines the max number of simultaneous requests that can be handled." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153727/tomcat-configuring-maxthreads-and-acceptcount-in-http-connector

Comment: basically, maxThreads will determine the maximum value of maxActive. Those values are interdependent. Make sure maxThreads is greater of equal to maxActive.

Comment: This is super helpful... where can i actually see the number of maxActive? I tried the context.xml file but it is not in that one for me...

Comment: I'm doing a research on maxActives location right now... I'll write about it as soon as I'll get the solution

Comment: So far so good, those are the best instructions I've got, right from the source. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: You'll find details about maxActive in the "2. Context configuration" section. Though, all the points are essential for a good configuration.

Comment: I can't move this 'chat' as i've only just joined. we are running on sqlserver, not my sql - which may make a difference? Is there a way to send you a private message?

Comment: Honestly, I made suggestions only from current researches. I'm sure you'll get your answers if you ride on Google a bit. Glad I could give some ideas.

Comment: Thanks loads!! Really appreciate it!