# tomcat - ratio between HTTP Connector maxThreads / acceptCount and JDBC pool maxActive

Tags: java, tomcat, httpconnection, jdbc-pool

Is there something as a common sense accepted ratio between the

- HTTP Connector **maxThreads** (max HTTP threads handling the users requests),
- HTTP Connector **acceptCount** (max queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use)
- DB pool **maxActive** (max DB connections in the pool) configuration properties

when it comes to a web  base application using tomcat with heavy usage of the database ?

What I mean is that for example we have almost each HTTP request connection is using the database intensively. So, when we have, f.e., much less configured DP pool **maxActive** (e.g. 100) while the HTTP Connector **maxThreads**  (e.g. 200) is twice bigger. 
Then there could be a possibility to have one and same DB connection to be shared between the HTTP connections. And that could leads to **heavy DB usage** / **DB stalls connections**.

I  am aware that web HTTP requests configuration in most of the cases has no  relation with the database pool configuration, but are there common cases/practices for a ratio between the properties (maxThreads/acceptCount maxActive) ? E.g. is a common practice the HTTP maxThreads to be larger than the DB maxActive (but thinking 100% larger is too much as per our example - could be let's say 20 or 50% max larger? ) and let's say  we have accpetCount with a bigger value, so to queue the HTTP requests by the time the others HTTP requests are processed by the application ?

There is similar question here: [Tomcat - Configuring maxThreads and acceptCount in Http connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153727/tomcat-configuring-maxthreads-and-acceptcount-in-http-connector) but with no more precise  answer to it

Answer (score 1):

First, a few clarifications:

- JDBC connections are not shared between threads to avoid breaking the isolation requirement. If the pool is exhausted the request will wait in a queue until a connections is assigned or a timeout occurs.
- Requests are served as they arrive up to **maxThreads** value, any additional requests are placed in a queue up to **acceptCount** value.

> **acceptCount**: The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests **when all possible request processing threads are in use**.

- **maxActive** is the bottleneck in your example so requests beyond that number will be waiting for a db connection. More precisely, the bottleneck is on the db connection pool.You won't get stalled db connections but rather threads waiting for a connection from the pool.

That said, there's not much value on finding a ratio between those values since **maxActive** will impose the limit. **maxThreads >= maxActive** is the obvious rule of thumb.

**maxThreads** will never be reached unless your application load says so but then your database pool should be able to cope with that load or your app will fail.

Tuning performance in this case is more about adjusting database connections pool and thread pool dynamics than setting limits. Once limits are reached there's not much to do, either find the code causing the slowness or scaling up.

Pool dynamics refers to minimum idle conn/threads, how long are kept idle, how many new entries in the pool are created at once, etc.

Hope this helps!

[Tomcat 7 HTTP connector docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: Thank you Luis for your descriptive response. Following your opinion, in order to avoid http threads to wait for a DB connection (we are assuming the users http requests are using intensively the DB) maybe is worth to make both values maxActive and maxThreads more similar in a meaning the value of maxThreads to be not much more bigger than the value of maxActive, as we could face in that case some frontend stall connections (as the frontend http threads will wait for an available db connection) ? E.g. maxActive=100 and maxThreads=130 or similar - but not double/triple the number of maxThreads

Comment: maxThreads=200 by default, why not leaving it as is? Lowering the value will not improve performance. On the other hand, stalled connections are probably caused by the app not answering on time. Perhaps maxActive=100 is not enough for your workload. Performance tuning is about finding bottlenecks and fixing them rather than setting limits.

Comment: yeah, but in our case the http threads are waiting for a db connection from the pool, when the db pool is full -all db connections are being used by the other http threads. Making both properties with similar values could potentially avoid stall connections, and scaling up horizontally the application itself - the number of instances.Unfortunately, increasing the number of the db connections per instance will constraint on the other side the DB-limits of DB connections to the DB instance.At the end is a combination of H scale up/maxThreads/maxActive - diff perf tests will show best combination

Comment: So If I need a jdbc connection for any http request setting maxThreads == maxActive is good ? And if I have some other threads (cron or whatever) may be maxThreads < maxActive of 5 connections ? I think that default conf is in other way because of static file requests that no need jdbc usually.

Comment: maxActive should follow what maxThreads dictates in some way and that depends on http requests load. Both should accommodate to serve the max stable load on your application plus some reasonable overhead. `maxThreads < maxActive` is not a usual case I guess, jdbc pool could be oversized in that case.